# How to throw an exception?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show a message on the screen but I don't want to end the process. Is there any way of doing it?

```
        var nonValidPolicies = Policies2RedistributeBankStatementAmountFor.Where(p => p.PolicyIsNotValid);
        if (nonValidPolicies.Any())
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Something");
```

Comment: MessageBox? If you throw an exception and it is not caught the program will end.

Comment: you can use ```finally``` block. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

Comment: Have you tried using `try {  SomeMethod();  } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("An Exception was thrown"); }`?

Comment: See also [unhandled exception handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-5.0). But this is probably best used as a last resort to log/display exceptions before quitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an exception, that means the code is not working, as desired, at the run time. When the exception is thrown, the control jumps to the parent method to look for the exception handler (try-catch). In case the handler is missing, the control goes one method higher and so on.

In order to address the problem of continuity, try to break the whole method into smaller methods. The idea is to corner out the troublesome code which might throw exception, and wrap it inside a try-catch. And in the parent method handle it gracefully.

Now, looking at the code snippet given above, it is absolutely a bad idea to throw exception for a known problem. Exceptions should be for the scenarios which are unknown at the runtime like connection failure, items not found etc. In the above scenario, you are checking for existence of elements and throwing exception. Instead return a message, so that parent method knows it and handles the situation. Better to use asynchronous method.

Comment: My only point is showing a message to the user without using MessageBox...

Comment: In that case, I would use delegates (Action, Func etc). Whenever the condition fails, call the Action/Func method. But NEVER THROW exceptions which are known. Very bad programming and reviewer will not be happy. Cheers.